# Calculating the numerical value of the regularized generalized hypergeometric function

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I'm trying to calculate the numerical value of the regularized generalized hypergeometric functions:

$\qquad \sf{HypergeometricPFQRegularized}^{(\{1\},\{0,0\},0)}(\{-1.5\},\{-1.,-0.5\},3600.)$

I tried

```
HypergeometricPFQRegularized^({0}, {0, 1} , 0)[{-1.5}, {-1., -0.5}, 3600.]
```

but I got the expression returned unevaluated

> `HypergeometricPFQRegularized^({1}, {0, 0}, 0))[{-1.5}, {-1., -0.5}, 3600.]`

*Mathematica* didn't calculate it numerically. Is there a way to get numerical values?

Comment: In Mathematica functions are called with `[square brackets]` not `(parens)`.  Additionally, indices on functions are not written with `^` but are passed as parameters to the function.  Take a look at http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQRegularized.html for more details on the syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately, even after entering the correct `N[Derivative[{1}, {0, 0}, 0][HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{-3/2}, {-1, -1/2}, 3600]]`, it still doesn't work. Let me see what I can do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use high precision:

```
SetPrecision[
  (HypergeometricPFQRegularized^({0}, {1, 0}, 0))[{-1.5}, {-1., -0.5}, 3600.],
  100]
```

it gives:

> `-2.8734042033205156581184947784*10^34`

Answer (score 3):

Set at least one parameter or variable to a high precision numeric value or numerically evaluate the exact expression using arbitrary precision.

```
$Version

(*  "10.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)"  *)

Derivative[{1}, {0, 0}, 0][HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{a}, {b1, 
   b2}, z] /. {a -> -3/2, b1 -> -1, b2 -> -1/2, z -> 3600.0`60}

(*  4.070133*10^52  *)

Derivative[{1}, {0, 0}, 0][HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{a}, {b1, 
   b2}, z] /. {a -> -3/2, b1 -> -1, b2 -> -0.5`60, z -> 3600}

(*  4.070133*10^52  *)

Derivative[{1}, {0, 0}, 0][HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{a}, {b1, 
   b2}, z] /. {a -> -3/2, b1 -> -1.0`60, b2 -> -1/2, z -> 3600}

(*  4.070133*10^52  *)

Derivative[{1}, {0, 0}, 0][HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{a}, {b1, 
   b2}, z] /. {a -> -1.5`60, b1 -> -1, b2 -> -1/2, z -> 3600}

(*  4.070133*10^52  *)
```

EDIT: After restart, last entry did not evaluate until arbitrary precision was increased and then only with warning message. However, result agrees with results above.

```
N[Derivative[{1}, {0, 0}, 0][
   HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{-3/2}, {-1, -1/2}, 3600], 75]

(*  N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating (HypergeometricPFQRegularized^({1},{0,0},0))[{-(3/2)},{-1,-(1/2)},3600]. >>

4.07013311778051868807295020202207635064552896440315759211918737043238\
348*10^52  *)
```

Comment: What version are you on? For some reason, this doesn't work on 10.3.

Comment: @J.M. - I am using 10.3 on a Mac. Note edit above.

Comment: Huh, it worked after restarting. But, I've also noticed that if you try to evaluate at machine precision first before trying arbitrary precision, the thing remains unevaluated. Bizarre...